# Concatenate multiple columns separately across multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to concatenate two columns separately across multiple rows of data in SQL Server that are joined between two tables.

For instance, I have an "association" table and "market" table as shown below"

```
Association:

user_id |  role_id  | market_id
-------------------------------
1       |     a     |     1
1       |     a     |     2
2       |     c     |     3
2       |     c     |     4
2       |     c     |     5

Market:

market_id | market_name
-----------------------
1         | Arizona
2         | Utah
3         | Indiana
4         | Illinois
5         | Kentucky
```

I need to concatenate the market_id in the Association table into a single value, per user id, as well as bring in the concatenated market names from the Market table, with my desired output looking like:

```
user_id |  role_id  |  market_ids   | market_names
--------------------------------------------------
1       |     a     |     1,2       | Arizona,Utah
2       |     c     |    3,4,5      | Indiana,Illinois,Kentucky
```

Now, I am able to successfully concatenate the market id's but still end up with multiple rows of data for each market using the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.user_id,
    a.role_id,
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + market_id  AS [text()]
            FROM Association aa
            WHERE a.user_id = aa.user_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [market_ids],
        SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + market_name  AS [text()]
            FROM Market bb
            WHERE a.market_id = bb.market_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Market Name]
FROM
    Association a
    INNER JOIN
    Market b
        ON a.market_id = d.market_id
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the second concatenation?

Answer (score 5):

A CTE with a Row_Number() to keep the presentation sequence should do the trick

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select A.*
          ,B.Market_Name
          ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By user_id,role_id order by a.market_id)
     From   Association A
     Join   Market B on A.market_id=B.market_id
)
Select Distinct
       user_id
      ,role_id
      ,market_ids   = stuff((Select concat(',',market_id  ) From cte Where user_id=A.user_id and role_id=A.role_id Order By RN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
      ,market_names = stuff((Select concat(',',market_name) From cte Where user_id=A.user_id and role_id=A.role_id Order By RN For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
 From  cte A
```

**Returns**

```
user_id role_id market_ids  market_names
1       a       1,2         Arizona,Utah
2       c       3,4,5       Indiana,Illinois,Kentucky
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `Stuff()` over `Substring()`. Anyways, Basically for Market name, You should do your association join in your sub query and then join both association tables on users id.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a.user_id,
    a.role_id,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(market_id  as varchar(25))
            FROM Association aa
            WHERE a.[user_id] = aa.[user_id]
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1,'') [market_ids],
        STUFF(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + market_name 
            FROM Market bb
          Inner join Association aaa on aaa.market_id = bb.market_id
            WHERE a.user_id = aaa.user_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1, 1,'') [Market Name]
FROM  Association a
```

Your original query can be written as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.[user_id],
    a.role_id,
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + cast(market_id  as varchar(25)) AS [text()]
            FROM #Association aa
            WHERE a.[user_id] = aa.[user_id]
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [market_ids],
        SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + market_name  AS [text()]
            FROM #Market bb
          INNER JOIN #Association aaa on aaa.market_id = bb.market_id
            WHERE a.user_id = aaa.user_id
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Market Name]
FROM  #Association a
```